# the boundary normal vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Suppose $X, Y$ are convex compact sets in $\mathbb R^n$ and $z \in  \mathbb R^n$.

Would it be the case that

$$\max_{x\in X}  [ \langle x, z \rangle-\max_{y\in Y} \langle x  ,y \rangle ]=\max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y} \langle x, z-y \rangle =\min_{y\in Y} \max_{x\in X}  \langle x, z-y \rangle $$

In this way, I may calculate the  $x^*$ (a subclass of normal vectors in $X$) that solves

$$\max_{x\in X}  [ \langle x, z \rangle-\max_{y\in Y} \langle x  ,y \rangle ]$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is true. The first equation follows from the $-\max(\cdots)=\min(-\cdots)$. The second follows from a generalization of the minimax theorem. For example you can use [Sion's minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem/). All the conditions on the function $f$ are satisfied trivially in your case because your function is linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer is very helpful.